# How to copy images to web folder with assetic

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I can't believe that I'm not able to google this...

So, I have a `symfony2` application, and I installed `jQuery UI` with `Composer`. That means i have project structure like this:

```
/app/
/src/
/vendor/components/jqueryui/
/web/
```

I have assetic set up to copy js/css files from the vendor folder to web. That works fine. Config:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        javascripts:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jqueryui/ui/jquery-ui.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jqueryui/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-cs.js
        stylesheets:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jqueryui/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css
            filters: cssrewrite
```

After assetic:dump i have

```
/web/js
/web/css
```

cssrewrite rewrites images/image.png to ../images/image.png. I guess that's ok, assumes a /web/images directory with said images.

Now the question is: How do I copy the images from /vendor/components/jqueryui/themes/redmond/images to /web/images?

Or is there another best practice to do that? Excuse me if it's and obvious thing, I'm a .NET guy, just trying out PHP.

Comment: Have you found yourself an answer to this? I'm stuck at the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

My answer probably isn't spot-on because I haven't tried this with vendor files but this is what worked for me:

```
app/console assets:install
```

It copies all of your public resources to your web directory.

[This answer by user1814739](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200340/2040520) helped me understand this and may provide additional information for you.

Also consider this [advice from the Symfony Blog](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command):

> Although developers usually execute the command without any option, most of the time it's better to execute it with the `--symlink` option. This makes a symbolic link of your assets instead of actually copying their files. This means that any change in the content of the web assets will have immediate effect in the application.