# Assets with or without Assetic in Symfony2 are driving me crazy

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, symfony, assetic

I am having a problem with my project assets when deploying them in a shared hosting. The point is that on my development server, I can create virtual host without any problems but in the shared hosting I have not this possibility when more I can create a subdomain and point it to the web project folder.

In my local server I created a virtual host and pointing to `/var/www/html/tanane` and I access trough URL as `tanane` (ServerName) but in a shared hosting but this varies a bit and the content of the project is inside a subfolder in the root path, for example: `/public_html/tanane` and I reach it from the URL`tanane.com/tanane/web/`. Apparently this is causing a issue and assets are lost and many fail to load, mostly those with sources like Twitter Bootstrap and FontAwesome. I have tried everything as you can see in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669103/fontawesome-fonts-fail-after-assetsinstall-and-asseticdump) but I have not accomplished anything yet.

This is what I did til now:

- Try this syntax `{{ asset('/bundles/css/somecss.css') }}` works for some but others not, [example](http://tanane.com/tanane/web/ml).

  **Problem:** The CSS rule

  ```
  .contactenos, .contactenos:hover, .e-shop, .e-shop:hover, .faq, .faq:hover, .fctjur, .fctjur:hover, .fctnat, .fctnat:hover, .vendidos, .vendidos:hover {
      background: url(/bundles/template/images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
  }
  ```

  works fine on local server but in shared hosting I need to change to:

  ```
  .contactenos, .contactenos:hover, .e-shop, .e-shop:hover, .faq, .faq:hover, .fctjur, .fctjur:hover, .fctnat, .fctnat:hover, .vendidos, .vendidos:hover {
      background: url(/tanane/web/bundles/template/images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
  }
  ```

  Which not works at local server then.

  - As the post I leave shows, I tried a lot of things with Assetic without success. Can anyone suggest me something else? Perhaps something in `.htaccess` or some other place? Any help, advice?

Comment: Can you run app/console on your shared host?

Comment: did you try to use the path relative to your CSS file? like ../template/images/sprites.png

Comment: @Cerad I don't think so, I just setup all in my development server,and upload all except `/app/cache` folder, is the only way I know to deploy in a shared hosting without SSH access

Comment: I'm lucky enough to have ssh access.  @Jacobson's solution will probably help.  I'd suggest setting up your local machine to match your shared host so the exact same urls are used.  Might make trouble shooting easier.

Comment: @Cerad SOT but, which hosting did you use? Or you have a VPS or something else?

Comment: I use telavant.com.  They give me full ssh access to my account.  Been with them since 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use relative paths on your CSS.

```
.contactenos, .contactenos:hover, .e-shop, .e-shop:hover, .faq, .faq:hover, .fctjur, .fctjur:hover, .fctnat, .fctnat:hover, .vendidos, .vendidos:hover {
    background: url(../template/images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Still not working, take a look [here](http://tanane.com/tanane/web/ml) buttons below "Tanane" logo are not loaded

Comment: This has no relation to CSS. Your images src attribute is corrupted.