# Path for fonts in specific folder (/web/fonts)

Tags: symfony, assetic

I am starting a Symfony 3 project.

My CSS files are in `/web/css`.
The CSS files need to get fonts in a font folder at the same level than the CSS folder ( = `/web/fonts`)

I'm using assetic for CSS and JS files.

When I'm in prod, everything is OK. The CSS files looks in `/MyApp/web/fonts/somefont.ttf` and find the font.

But under app_dev.php, the file looks for `/MyApp/web/app_dev.php/fonts/somefont.ttf` which doesn't work.

How can I manage that ? Do I have to do something with assetic ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the twig function `asset` like explained in the [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html).

Comment: You mean using it in my CSS files to refer to the fonts, don't you ?

Comment: In your CSS, you use a realtive path (ex: `../fonts/somefont.ttf`) and in your HTML, you use asset like `{{ asset('css/example.css') }}`.

Comment: CSS files do work well, both in dev or prod. In dev, fonts don't load.

Answer (score 0):

Since your web folder is the root path for Symfony on the web, folders within the web folder are relative to that folder. You probably should use asset like @romqin state, but you can also try something like this (in twig):

```
{% block stylesheets %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"> 
{% endblock %}
```

Don't try to specify the absolute path, but just the relative path. This works for me both in DEV and PROD.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I could solve my problem using this : [Symfony2 - Assetic - css font icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443773/symfony2-assetic-css-font-icons/24777989#24777989)

Thanks for helping !