# Install assets with fonts

Tags: css, symfony, fonts

I am having an issue with the command `assets:install --symlink --relative` . I have in my `MyBundle/Resorces/public/` two dirs: `css/font-awesome.css` and `fonts/...` with all `woff`, `woff2` files etc.

When I run `assets:install --symlink --relative` I get a symlink in my `web/bundles/my-bundle/` to my `css` directory with css files, but not to my font directory. This `font-awesome.css` file addresses font files like this:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
 src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),....
```

and since there is no symlink generated to my fonts the css file can't find fonts it needs.

What ought I to do in this situation?

Comment: I think I found a right solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443773/symfony2-assetic-css-font-icons sorry for duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - Assetic - css font icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443773/symfony2-assetic-css-font-icons)